# How to add Intent inside Progressdialog?

Tags: java, android

i want to add intent after progressdialog done , i already add intent , but its not work, i get error when compile.

private void showProgressDialog() {

```
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Validating");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    new CountDownTimer(28000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int[] countTimer = new int[] {.......};
            String[] setMessage = new String[]{......};
            count=count+1;
            for(int i=0; i<countTimer.length; i++) {
                if (count == countTimer[i]){
                    progressDialog.setMessage(setMessage[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //the progress is finish
            count=0;
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }.start();
}
```

i get this error

```
Error:(66, 28) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous CountDownTimer>,Class<Main2Activity>)constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable(argument mismatch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` refers to `CountDownTimer`, trying using `YourActivity.this` or somthing similar